UserInfo.getSessionId() returns null in record-triggered flow with scheduled path invocable Apex
Given a record-triggered flow

with a scheduled Path (e.g. execute 3 days later)
that includes an invocable Apex method that fetches a session Id via UserInfo.getSessionId()

Then the value returned is NULL, despite the running user being an active Salesforce user.
The documentation on getSessionId() states:

You can use getSessionId() both synchronously and asynchronously. In asynchronous Apex (Batch, Future, Queueable, or Scheduled Apex), this method returns the session ID only when the code is run by an active, valid user. When the code is run by an internal user, such as the automated process user or a proxy user, the method returns null.
As a best practice, ensure that your code handles both cases: when a session ID is or is not available.

The doc is ambiguous/silent on this specific use case of record-triggered flows with scheduled paths.
How do I get a valid session Id?

I'd be interested to know why you want a session ID...

sessionId required by an internal service that wanted to verify that incoming REST call was coming from our SFDC org. I remonstrated that there was a better way but they wanted to di it this way because they had done it that way for the last 15 years

So how does a session ID prove it's coming from the org? Do they use it to call back into the org or something? If they do, that feels... excessive... and likely to consume REST API limits unnecessarily...?

yes, they call back into the org using https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_using_userinfo_endpoint.htm&type=5 @PhilW

Oh, at least that won't consume API limits.

You used to be able to use $API_Session_Id in Flows but this was removed in a Summer 23 Release Update (I have no idea if that even worked for scheduled paths back then)
Since I happened to have the UnofficialSF.com base pack (highly useful for lots of things) installed, I followed the instructions to acquire a sessionId from their instructions.  I created a small method in my class Util
public static String getSessionId() {
  if (UserInfo.getSessionId() != null) {return UserInfo.getSessionId();}
  return  Test.isRunningTest() 
      ? 'TEST_SESSION_ID' 
      : Page.usf3__GenerateSessionIdForLWC.getContent().toString().replace('\n','');        
}

If you don't happen to have the Flow Base Pack installed, create you own Visualforce page like this:
<apex:page id="SessionIdGenerator" contentType="application/json">
{!$Api.Session_ID}
</apex:page>

Notes

I had to add the replace('\n','') as the VF page prepends a \n to the result

getContent() can't be executed in test methods hence the check.

If you want to see the session Id that would otherwise be suppressed in debug logs, you can do the following
System.debug('Prepend '00D with ' + 
      sessionId.substring(3));  // sessionIds start with orgId that 
                                //  always starts with 00D 




Could you make use of a session cache in the Platform Cache to hold the ID?

Not sure I follow (@philw) -- Flow starts on day(0), scheduled path executes at day+14 or +30) - cache would have expired by then, no?

Ignore me - I wasn't thinking in days of delay, but in the small number of hours.
